# Serializing Protobuf Reflection

Tags: reflection, protocol-buffers, marshalling

Is there a way to through reflection to retrieve the equivalent of the .proto file which generated a protobuf object class from an instance of an object?

Essentially, it should be possible for a client to get this definition and run the equivalent of protoc on the type that was serialized such that it could decode future data (principally for dynamically typed languages).

I could send the .proto files, but then I need to worry about keeping the files in sync with the objects rather than having the protoc output be able to dump the .proto definition.

Comment: What platform/language/runtime is this? It can matter

Comment: The sender would be a C++ application. Receiver would be some dynamic language eg python.